# Unix pattern matching using vim

Tags: regex, unix, vim

Dealing with random files, which has patterns like

```
Jon Smith-db/his-wife.db/his-keeds.db
Jon Smith-db/his-wife.db/his-siblings/his-k1ds.db
....
....
```

I need to replace last string `his-keeds.db` and similar typos to blank, so my attempt is

```
:1,$s/\/.+\.db$//g
```

but doesn't work. I was able to do it using awk and perl but failed doing so in vim inbuilt editor. Can anyone help?

Comment: what is `and similar typos`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this would do the job:

```
:%s#/[^/]*\.db$#/#
```

if you don't want the ending slash:

```
:%s#/[^/]*\.db$##
```

Comment: Thanks Kent. What's the first '#' after s (substitution) ?

Comment: `#` could be any single character, e.g. `@`, `;` ... I used it because I don't have to escape the slashes.

Comment: @CuriousMind thx. yours was also very close. you just neglected the greedy `.+` change `.` into `[^/]` would work too. (`g` is not needed, since you have `$` in pattern)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
:g/his-keeds.db$/s///g
```

instead

Comment: Marc - his-keeds.db can be anything, the whole file has typos, so it can be 'his-keeeeeeds.db' or 'his-k1234ds.db' too. Otherwise, it would have been straightforward.

Comment: then try an inverse regex. anything that is *NOT* his-kids.db

Comment: apart from the requirement. the two `g` (`:g` and `/g`) are not necessary. just `:%s/his-keeds.db$//`. but the substitution won't fail with them